# JSONP not displaying data in HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

This is my PHP page, on my fictional domain http://www.myradiostation1.localhost (testing domain, not web-accessible). It is similar to, but not the same as http://www.vikingfm.co.uk/on-air/station-schedule/ - and is a testing copy for my own CSS changes to the stylesheet/website design changes

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" media="all">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <div class="content-inner">
                                              <div class="row">
          <div class="column size-10">
          <div class="large-schedule-widget main-col main-col-large widgetbox">
                     <table class="schedule-table">
                <!-- column headers -->
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hide">Units</th>
                        <th>Hours</th>
                        <th>Monday</th>
                        <th class="active">Tuesday</th>
                        <th>Wednesday</th>
                        <th>Thursday</th>
                        <th>Friday</th>
                        <th>Saturday</th>
                        <th>Sunday</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr id="units-0">
                        <td class="hide">0</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">00:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="units-1">
                        <td class="hide">1</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                    </tr>

                    <!-- echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    <tr id="units-2">
                        <td class="hide">2</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">01:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->

                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-3">
                        <td class="hide">3</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->                 
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-4">
                        <td class="hide">4</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">02:00</td>

                    <tr id="units-5">
                        <td class="hide">5</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->

                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-6">
                        <td class="hide">6</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">03:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-7">
                        <td class="hide">7</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-8">
                        <td class="hide">8</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">04:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-9">
                        <td class="hide">9</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-10">
                        <td class="hide">10</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">05:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-11">
                        <td class="hide">11</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-12">
                        <td class="hide">12</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">06:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-13">
                        <td class="hide">13</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-14">
                        <td class="hide">14</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">07:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                    <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-15">
                        <td class="hide">15</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-16">
                        <td class="hide">16</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">08:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-17">
                        <td class="hide">17</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-18">
                        <td class="hide">18</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">09:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-19">
                        <td class="hide">19</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-20">
                        <td class="hide">20</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time current_time" rowspan="2">10:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-21">
                        <td class="hide">21</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-22">
                        <td class="hide">22</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">11:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-23">
                        <td class="hide">23</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-24"> 
                        <td class="hide">24</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">12:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        </tr>

                    <tr id="units-25">
                        <td class="hide">25</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-26">
                        <td class="hide">26</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">13:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                        </tr>

                    <tr id="units-27">
                        <td class="hide">27</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-28">
                        <td class="hide">28</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">14:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                        </tr>

                    <tr id="units-29">
                        <td class="hide">29</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-30">
                        <td class="hide">30</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">15:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-31">
                        <td class="hide">31</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-32">
                        <td class="hide">32</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">16:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-33">
                        <td class="hide">33</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-34">
                        <td class="hide">34</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">17:00</td> 
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-35">
                        <td class="hide">35</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-36">
                        <td class="hide">36</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">18:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-37">
                        <td class="hide">37</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-38">
                        <td class="hide">38</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">19:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-39">
                        <td class="hide">39</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-40">
                        <td class="hide">40</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">20:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-41">
                        <td class="hide">41</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-42">
                        <td class="hide">42</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">21:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-43">
                        <td class="hide">43</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-44">
                        <td class="hide">44</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">22:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-45">
                        <td class="hide">45</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-46">
                        <td class="hide">46</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">23:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-47">
                        <td class="hide">47</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-48">
                        <td class="hide">48</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>                   


                </tbody>
            </table>
</div> <!-- end .main-col -->
<script>
var doFades = true;

var MyLocalhostStations = {
  Schedule : {}
};

$(document).ready(function(){

  MyLocalhostStations.Schedule.days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

  MyLocalhostStations.Schedule.Show = function () {
    _s = null;
    _startDate = null;
    _endDate = null;
    this.days = MyLocalhostStations.Schedule.days;
    _selector = '';

    this.setShow = function(s) {
      this._s = s;

      this._startDate = new Date( parseInt(s.startminutes, 10) * 1000);
      this._endDate = new Date(parseInt(s.endminutes, 10) * 1000 ); 

    };

    this.getEndDate = function(){
      return this._endDate;
    }

    this.getStartDate = function(){ 
      return this._startDate;
    }

    this._getShowDay = function (){
      return this.days[this.getStartDate().getDay()];
    };

    this._getShowUnitsTaken = function(){
      // if it's the same day
      return this._getEndUnits() - this._getStartUnits();
    };

    this._getEndUnits = function(){   
      if(this.getEndDate().getHours() == 0)
      {
        //console.log(this._s.longname  +' ends at midnight');
        return 48;
      }

      return this.getEndDate().getMinutes() !== 0 ? (this.getEndDate().getHours() * 2) : (this.getEndDate().getHours() * 2);
    };

    this._getStartUnits = function(){
      if(this.getStartDate().getHours() == 0)
      {
        return 0;
      }

      return this.getStartDate().getMinutes() !== 0 ? (this.getStartDate().getHours() * 2) : (this.getStartDate().getHours() * 2);
    };

    this.getCellPositions = function() {
      return {
        'start' : this.getStartDate(),
        'end' : this.getEndDate(),
        'colIndex' : this.getStartDate().getDay() + 2,
        'startUnits' : this._getStartUnits(),
        'endUnits' : this._getEndUnits(),
        'unitsTaken' : this._getShowUnitsTaken()
      }
    };

    this.pad = function(number){
      return number < 10 ? '0'+number : number; 
    };

    // return the table cell html.
    this.toHtml = function () {

      var d = new Date();
      var units = this._getStartUnits();

      var rowspan = this._getShowUnitsTaken();    
      var desc = this._s.description;
      var name = this._s.longname;

      var starttime   = this.pad(this.getStartDate().getHours()) + ':' + this.pad(this.getStartDate().getMinutes());
      var endtime   = this.pad(this.getEndDate().getHours()) + ':' + this.pad(this.getEndDate().getMinutes());

      var site = this._s.websitelink;

      var cls = this.isActive() ? 'current-program' : '';

      var isToday = this.getStartDate().getDay() === d.getDay() ? 'active-program' : '';

      var html = '<td class="schedule-show ' + isToday + ' ' + cls + '" rowspan="' + rowspan + '" data-start="' + this.getStartDate() + '" data-end="' + this.getEndDate() + '">';
        html += '<div>';
        html += '<a href="' + site + '" title="' + desc + '">' + name + '</a>';
        html += '</div>';
        if(doFades)
        {
          html += '<div class="schedule_details clearfix" style="display:none;">';
          html += '<img width="105px" height="105px" alt="' + desc + '" src="' + this._s.showimage + '">';
          html += '<strong>' + name + '</strong>';
          html += '<p>' + desc + '</p>';
          html += '<span>' + starttime + ' - ' + endtime +'</span>';
          html += '</div>';
        }
        html += '</td>';      

      return html;
    };

    this.setTableSelector = function(sel){
      this._selector = sel;
    };

    // check if we should add the active class.
    this.isActive = function(){
      var t = new Date();

      return  t >= this.getStartDate() && t <= this.getEndDate();
    };
  };

  MyLocalhostStations.Schedule.ScheduleGen = function(){

    return {
      insertShow : function(show) {
        var p = show.getCellPositions();

        $('tr#units-' + p.startUnits).append(show.toHtml());
      },

      init : function (stationName){
        var self = this;

        // load the schedule.
        $.getJSON('http://www.myradiostation2.localhost/schedule.php?callback=?', {
          name: 'North FM'
        }, function(json){
          // loop each show and append to our giant table.
          // this is well sick.

          if(json.success === false)
          {
            $('.content-inner table').remove();

            $('<div>errors</div>').appendTo('.content-inner');
          }
          else
          {
            var currentDay = '';
            var day = 0;
            // highlight the current time..
            var d = new Date();
            var weekStart = new Date();

            weekStart.setDate(d.getDate()-6-(d.getDay()||7));

            $.each(json.data.schedule, function(i, broadcast){


              var dStart = new Date( parseInt(broadcast.startminutes, 10) * 1000);
              var dEnd = new Date(parseInt(broadcast.endminutes, 10) * 1000 ); 


              /*// transform to a show object defined above, if the show spans 2 days we create two show objects.
              // IF THE SHOW STARTS/ENDS AT MIDNIGHT, DON'T SPLIT IT.
              if(dStart.getHours() !== 0 && dEnd.getHours() !== 0 && dStart.getDate() != dEnd.getDate())
              {
                var showOne = new MyLocalhostStations.Schedule.Show();
                showOne.setShow(broadcast);

                // set to midnight 
                showOne.getEndDate().setHours(0);
                showOne.getEndDate().setMinutes(dStart.getMinutes());


                // append first half of show.
                self.insertShow(showOne);

                // handle second half.
                var showTwo = new MyLocalhostStations.Schedule.Show();
                showTwo.setShow(broadcast);

                showTwo.getStartDate().setDate(showTwo.getStartDate().getDate() + 1);
                showTwo.getStartDate().setHours(0);
                showTwo.getStartDate().setMinutes(dEnd.getMinutes());

                //console.log('2nd Half Start: ' + showTwo.getStartDate());
                //console.log('2nd Half End: ' + showTwo.getEndDate());

                self.insertShow(showTwo);


              }
              else
              {*/
                var show = new MyLocalhostStations.Schedule.Show();

                show.setShow(broadcast);
                show.setTableSelector('table#schedule');

                // add the show to the table. Thankfully the order these come out the API means they get added 
                // in the right place. So don't change the schedule builder code!

                self.insertShow(show);
              //}


            });

            var days = MyLocalhostStations.Schedule.days;   

            // apply the current day / time classes 
            $('th:contains('+ days[d.getDay()]+')').addClass('active');

            $('td.time').each(function(i, cell){
              // get the value, convert to int. 
              var hours = $(cell).html().split(':')[0];

              // compare the hours with now, add class if matched. 
              if(parseInt(hours, 10) === d.getHours())
              {
                $(cell).addClass('current_time');
              }
            });
          }


          if(doFades)
          {
            // apply events to show info fade in / out.
            $('td.schedule-show').hover(function(){
              $(this).find('.schedule_details').fadeIn('fast');
            }, function(){
              $(this).find('.schedule_details').fadeOut('fast');
            });
          }
        });


      }
    };
  }();


  MyLocalhostStations.Schedule.ScheduleGen.init(twittiName);

});
</script>
```

and my JSONP code at http://www.myradiostation2.localhost/schedule.php?callback=?&name=North+FM:

```
    <?php
   header('Content-type: application/javascript;');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
  //db connection detils
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "test";
  $password = "test";
  $database = "myradiostation1";

  //make connection
  $server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
  $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

  //query the database
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS start, 
                                   DATE_FORMAT(end, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS end FROM radiostation1");

    //loop through and return results
  for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); $x < $numrows; $x++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    $shows[$x] = array("id" => $row["id"], "startminutes" => $row["startminutes"], "start" => $row["start"], "endminutes" => $row["endminutes"],"end" => $row["end"],"mediumname" => $row["mediumname"], "longname" => $row["longname"], "description" => $row["description"],"short_id" => $row["short_id"],"promomessage" => $row["promomessage"],"email" => $row["email"],"phonenumber" => $row["phonenumber"],"textnumber" => $row["textnumber"],"textprefix" => $row["textprefix"],"showimage" => $row["showimage"],"longdescription" => $row["longdescription"],"facebooklink" => $row["facebooklink"],"otherlink" => $row["otherlink"],"websitelink" => $row["websitelink"],"keywords" => $row["keywords"] );     
  }

  //echo JSON to page
  $response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($shows) . ");";
  echo $response;
```

The JSONP works, but my code is not displaying in the HTML table.

Why is my table blank and not displaying the code?

Comment: can you var_dump the json object and then paste the result here?

Comment: The content-type for JSONP is `application/javascript` not `application/json`.

Comment: You are vulnerable to the [Rosetta Flash JSONP attack](http://miki.it/blog/2014/7/8/abusing-jsonp-with-rosetta-flash/)

Comment: do you see any errors in browser console?

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure in PHP is just an array:

```
$foo = array(
  0 => array(... data from row #1 of the query),
  1 => array(... data from row #2 of the query),
  etc...
);
```

In JSON format,

```
[{..row1 data..},{..row2 data..},....,{..row n data..}]
```

Nowhere in that structure do you have a `success` key, or a `data` key. So `json.data` does not exist in your JS code, nor does `json.success`.

If you want that kind of structure, you'd have to be doing:

```
$foo = array(
   'success' => true,
   'data' => array()
);
```

and then

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $foo['data'][] = $row;
       ^^^^^^^^---- you don't have this.
}

echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($foo) . ")";
```

Comment: Damn you Gurus. This is a brilliant answer!

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you are returning is an array, it doesn't have a `data` property so `json.data.schedule` will error.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your code because you have a lots of thing, my advice is try to do one simple page with the ajax request and with one "for" see what is going on, and use some debug tools, and use console.log.

Ex

```
 <script>
 $.getJSON('http://www.myradiostation2.localhost/schedule.php?callback=?', {
      name: 'North FM'
    }, function(json){
       console.log(json);
       for(var key in json){
       console.log("********"+key+"*********");
       console.log(json[key]);
       }
       });
 </script>
```

This way you can see if all is working good with your request and if you have a good logic in your script, after you can take the object and try to put and see if the creation html is working fine, etc.

I know that is not the best answers, but is one way to debug your code.

And why you use jsonp? today normally you can use simple json.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP read first line please :) from a server in a different domain